# R ggplot: Weighted CDF

Tags: r, ggplot2, cdf

I'd like to plot a weighted CDF using `ggplot`. Some old non-SO discussions (e.g. [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2012-October/337288.html) from 2012) suggest this is not possible, but thought I'd reraise.

For example, consider this data:

```
df <- data.frame(x=sort(runif(100)), w=1:100)
```

I can show an unweighted CDF with

```
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + stat_ecdf()
```

[image]

How would I weight this by `w`? For this example, I'd expect an `x^2`-looking function, since the larger numbers have higher weight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a mistake in your answer.

This is the right code to compute the weighted ECDF:

```
df <- df[order(df$x), ]  # Won't change anything since it was created sorted
df$cum.pct <- with(df, cumsum(w) / sum(w))
ggplot(df, aes(x, cum.pct)) + geom_line()
```

The ECDF is a function `F(a)` equal to the sum of weights (probabilities) of observations where `x<a` divided by the total sum of weights.

But here is a more satisfying option that simply modifies the original code of the ggplot2 stat_ecdf:
https://github.com/NicolasWoloszko/stat_ecdf_weighted

Comment: Hi, the code in the github repo looks very interesting. could you add some guidelines how to safely "install/uninstall" it? thanks

Comment: @vagvaf, I'm not very experienced at this, but it just looks like an .R file to me, so I think you'll just have to copy the code after loading the `ggplot2` library (which will overwrite the `stat_ecdf` function). I think packages would be installed from GitHub with commands such as `library(devtools)`, then
`install_github("NicolasWoloszko/stat_ecdf_weighted")`.

Comment: The simplest way is to source the raw URL. Simply type `source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NicolasWoloszko/stat_ecdf_weighted/master/stat_ecdf_weighted.R")`. You can type `stat_ecdf` (without the parentheses) to see how the function is defined *before* and after you call Nicolas's script.