# ECDF plot in ggplot2 without expanding count variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, expand, ecdf

I have a dataframe which looks like

```
Height Count
173      2
184      3
193      1
```

Usually, to plot an empirical cumulative distribution function, one:
1) expands the dataframe by using e.g. splitstackshape's expandRows function to obtain the following:

```
output
173
173
184
184
184     
193
```

2) plots the ECDF using the output variable.

However, my dataframe is very large and expandRows yields an error of the 'cannot allocate vector of size X' type. Yet, what I would be interested in is an (even approximate) plot of the ECDF, rather than an expanded dataframe.

Is there a workaround to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your expected output is, can you give an example with the data? You might want to look at `geom_step` from `ggplot2`,

Comment: Possible duplicate of <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487457/r-ggplot-weighted-cdf>. In particular see the given [link](https://github.com/NicolasWoloszko/stat_ecdf_weighted).

Comment: To get the output variable, you could do: `rep(df$Height, df$Count)`; and if you need it in a dataframe: `data.frame(output = rep(df$Height, df$Count))`